# Is it possible changing the style of html captured by screen scraping?

Tags: asp.net, html

I need to screen scrape a web page and change its style to match the look and feel of the site where it will be displayed in. Is this possible? I'll be using asp.net to do the screen scraping.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you have any specific problem with this?

Comment: No problem, it's just the 1st time for me to use screen scraping and I was reading about how to do it and all the examples where just capturing the html as it is without applying css modification so I just wanted to know if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, absolutely. once you scrape the HTML and add it into your DOM, you can write up your CSS to target this HTML.